# Converting true/false to 0/1 boolean in a mixed dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have a dataframe with mixed data types. I want to create a function that goes through all the columns and converts any columns containing `True/False` to `int32` type `0/1`.  I tried a lambda function below, where d is my dataframe:

```
f = lambda x: 1 if x==True else 0
d.applymap(f)
```

This doesn't work, it converts all my non boolean columns to `0/1` as well. Is there a good way to go through the dataframe and leave everything everything untouched except the boolean columns and convert them to 0's and 1's? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data? The solution would honestly depend on the data.

Comment: The data would change in different use cases, that's why I wanted to create a function that is scalable. The columns in question however are of type boolean, so if there is a way to select only boolean columns in a dataframe to apply said function to, that would do the job I'm assuming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's modify your lambda to use an `isinstance` check:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: int(x) if isinstance(x, bool) else x)
```

Only values of type `bool` will be converted to `int`, everything else remains the same.

---

As a better solution, if the column types are scalar (and not "mixed" as I originally assumed given your question), you can instead use

```
u = df.select_dtypes(bool)
df[u.columns] = u.astype(int)
```

Comment: This works! However, is there a way to explicitly convert to int32 type instead of int64 which this seems to be doing?

Comment: @codingenthusiast Not easily with the first, but with the second you can use `df[u.columns] = u.astype(np.int32)`. As for the first, you could try `np.int32(x) instead of `int(x)` but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the columns using loc and change data type.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.randn(2), 'col2':[True, False], 'col3':[False, True]})

df.loc[:, df.dtypes == bool] = df.astype(int)



    col1      col2  col3
0   0.999358    1   0
1   0.795179    0   1
```

Comment: Ah, I see how I might have misunderstood "mixed" to mean "mixed data" per column.

Comment: @cs95, if it's mixed data per column, this won't work. May be OP will clarify

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe df, try:

```
df_1=df.applymap(lambda x: int(x) if type(x)==bool else x)
```